# Remove tuples in a 2D numpy array that satisfy 2 conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have a numpy array of tuples and I want to remove all tuples where the first value is less than 0 or the second element is greater than a number, n.
So if n = 10 and we had this array:

`[[-1, 5], [3, 11], [-4, 20]]`

It would become this:

`[[]]`

I'm guessing I need to use `np.delete` and `np.where` in a smart way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using logical indexing. I'm guessing in your example you meant that

```
[[-1, 5], [3, 11], [-4, 20]]
```

would become

```
[]
```

Since you said that the conditions are:

> I want to **remove** all tuples where the *first value is less than 0* **or** the *second element is greater than a number*, n.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[-1, 5], [3, 11], [-4, 20]])
>>> arr[~((arr[:,0] < 0) | (arr[:,1] > 10))]
array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int64)
```

Basically it's all down to expressing your logical requirement as the combination (through `|` and `&`) of different logical masks.

The `~` takes the inverse of the mask, since you said you wanted to **delete** elements that match your criteria. A better example of this method working is this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[-1, 5], [1, 1], [3, 11], [-4, 20], [2, 9]])
>>> arr[~((arr[:,0] < 0) | (arr[:,1] > 10))]
array([[1, 1], [2, 9]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[-1, 5], [3, 11], [-4, 20]])
>>> mask = (A[:,0]>0) & (A[:,1] > 10)
>>> A[mask]
array([[ 3, 11]])
```

The idea is to express your condition using an expression as in `mask`.